# Umbraco - Returning all grandchildren

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I have a section on my site which has been split into categories and I am trying to build a page which has all of the the content under each category. I am however stuggling to get the right query to achieve this.

This is my structure:

`Home
- Section
  - Category 1
    - Content
    - Content
  - Category 2
    - Content
    - Content`

and this is what I have tried playing with but I think im getting the logic wrong

```
> var sectionContent =
> Model.Content.Site().Children("section").Children("category").Children("content").Where(x
> => x.IsVisible());
> 
> @foreach(var item in sectionContent){  @item.name }
```

What I am looking to get is all the content under the section.

can someone please showing what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [`Descendants(string nodeTypeAlias)`](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/templating/mvc/querying#traversing)

```
using Umbraco.Web;

var sectionContent = Model.Content.Site().Children("section").Descendants("content").Where(x => x.IsVisible());
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply. When I tried your code I got an error stating there are no definitions for Decendants - should I be including a reference to get this to work?

Comment: @Sparkz Yes! You need to include `using Umbraco.Web;`